# Says type is non-optional but prints optional

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
let result_string = "\(String(describing: value))"
```

because I need to convert this from type Any to String.  However when I print result string, it prints:

```
optional(abcd)
```

How do I make it print just

```
abcd
```

?

When I tried the other fixes for optionals it told me that result_string is not optional and didn't let me force unwrap.

**EDIT:**
Value was an optional, so force unwrapping it fixed my problem.

```
let result_string = "\(String(describing: value!))"
```

Comment: My guess: `value` is an optional ...

Comment: @Martin R So should I try force unwrapping value?

Comment: @MartinR Thank You, force unwrapping this fixed my problem.

Comment: force unwrap may crash if the value is nil

Comment: @AthreyaDaniel your result_string is optional but  value which is type Any is not optional and you are trying to force unwrap non-optional value.

Comment: `String(describing:)` does what its name says: it *describes* the object you pass to it, it doesn't convert anything. It is not meant to convert objects to strings and use them in code. It's a debugging tool. The correct way to convert to string is to use the `String()` initializer (or interpolation), with a non-optional value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if let res = value {
  print(res)
}
```

**OR**

```
guard let res = value { return }
print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try like below:

var value : Any? = "abcd"

let result_string = value as! String

print(result_string)

We have to downcast Any to string.
Worked in playground.

Comment: Sorry Prabhat but this is wrong. In your example, `result_string` is a non-optional string containing the literal string "Optional(value)". Same mistake as OP's.

Comment: @Moritz If value is type Any with optional then it will produce Optional(value) and I was consi

Comment: Please test your code in a Playground, Prabhat. You will see that you get "initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'", because as I said, in your example `result_string` is not an optional. Hint: "interpolation"... ;)

Comment: Thanks got it. We have to downcast value of type Any . I have edited the answer and verified it.

Comment: Well now your code has no errors, sure, but it doesn't answer OP's question. It doesn't solve their problem.

Comment: Kindly provide the solution.